# Как вставить таблицу в документ Word на место текстовой метки?

Tags: c#, com, ms-word

Обновление: вопрос закрыт. К черту всё это. В ТЗ нет чётких указаний, поэтому заместо таблицы вставлю текстовый список.

Имеется таблица в виде объекта `DataTable`. Нужно вставить её на место определённого набора символов в документе-шаблоне.

Замену текст-на-текст можно выполнить так (куча missingObj нужан для обхода багов):

```
    using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

    Word._Application application;
    Word._Document document;
    Object missingObj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Object trueObj = true;
    Object falseObj = false;

    private void create_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            application = new Word.Application();
            Object templatePathObj;
            templatePathObj = "template.dot";  

            try {
                document = application.Documents.Add(ref  templatePathObj, 
                    ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
            }
            catch (Exception error) {
                document.Close(ref falseObj, ref  missingObj, ref missingObj);
                application.Quit(ref missingObj, ref  missingObj, ref missingObj);
                document = null;
                application = null;
                throw error;
            }

            object strToFindObj = "%метка%";
            object replaceStrObj = "текст для вставки";
            Word.Range wordRange;
            object replaceTypeObj;
            replaceTypeObj = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
            for (int i = 1; i <= document.Sections.Count; i++) {
                wordRange = document.Sections[i].Range;
                Word.Find wordFindObj = wordRange.Find;
                object[] wordFindParameters = new object[15] { strToFindObj, missingObj, 
                    missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, 
                    missingObj, replaceStrObj, replaceTypeObj, missingObj, missingObj, 
                    missingObj, missingObj };
                wordFindObj.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
                    null, wordFindObj, wordFindParameters);
        }
        application.Visible = true;
    }
```

Как следует скорректировать этот код, чтобы он принимал на вход таблицу и вносил её в нужное место в документе?

В этом примере замена происходит внутри объекта `Range`, который представляет собой фрагмент документа, который может полноценно описывать содержимое документа Word (таблицы, форматирование).

UPD: Внесу ясность. В моей программе формируется объект `DataTable`, содержащий таблицу. Нужно внутри документа Word вставить эту таблицу на место набора символов `%метка%`.

Comment: Вы пробовали создавать таблицу вот так https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192485(v=office.11).aspx и вставлять её как описано в вашем вопросе здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421684/how-to-insert-table-into-word-document-in-place-of-text-mark  ?

Comment: @FLCL, не вникал полностью в статью. Там имеется в виду вставка таблицы на место некоторой метки которую можно установить через MS Word? Другой вариант не подходит.

Comment: @FLCL, для работы с документом я использую OleDbAdapter, так что вариант с ADO.NET с моим описанием не клеится. И да, вы дали ссылку на копию этого же вопроса.

Comment: Вот пример, в котором используется OleDbConnection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa168492(v=office.11).aspx для той же задачи. Заменив в нём выполнение команды на адаптер вы, вероятно, получите требуемое решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начиная с .Net 4.0 улучшена поддержка COM и теперь все вызовы можно писать короче (без `missingObj` и `ref`):

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Data;

var dataTable = new DataTable();
// создаем и заполняем таблицу

Word._Application wordApplication = new Word.Application();
Word._Document wordDocument = null;
wordApplication.Visible = true;

var templatePathObj = @"template.dot";

try {
    wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(templatePathObj);
}
catch (Exception exception) {
    if (wordDocument != null) {
        wordDocument.Close(false);
        wordDocument = null;
    }
    wordApplication.Quit();
    wordApplication = null;
    throw;
}

wordApplication.Selection.Find.Execute("%метка%");
Word.Range wordRange = wordApplication.Selection.Range;

var wordTable = wordDocument.Tables.Add(wordRange,
    dataTable.Rows.Count, dataTable.Columns.Count);

for (var j = 0; j < dataTable.Rows.Count; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < dataTable.Columns.Count; k++) {
        wordTable.Cell(j + 1, k + 1).Range.Text = dataTable.Rows[j][k].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Исходная задача не решается с помощью [слияния данных MS Excel и MS Word](http://www.excelworld.ru/publ/hacks/integration/excel_with_other_office/58-1-0-127)?

Comment: Нет. Данные идут из базы данных.

Comment: @InfernumDeus, из базы данных легко экспортировать в csv, оттуда в excel? Или есть вообще инструмент для [запросов к mysql из excel](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Connect-to-a-MySQL-database-Power-Query--8760c647-88b9-409d-b312-6ea8f84a269b?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA) и еще куча вариантов по запросу mysql to excel

Comment: да и напрямую [из word можно в mysql обратиться](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-wordexcel.html)

Comment: Я добавляю таблицу в документ Word. В произвольном месте пишется `%метка%`, программа находит это место и вставляет туда таблицу на основе выборки из БД.

Comment: Добавил поясняющий комментарий.

Comment: Что мешает вместо %метка% вставлять запрос к mysql? (ну или найти+заменить %метка% на запрос) У вас программа как-то формирует данные? Можно же их обратно в mysql закидывать и оттуда word'ом подтягивать.

Comment: Я формирую запрос из данных, введённых в форму и по нему получаю часть таблицы из БД. Каким образом можно вставить запрос в документ Word? Если что, в данном случае, обязательно использовать MS Access.

Comment: @InfernumDeus, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-a-parameter-query-addf7cb7-ddf0-442f-a60c-cd7280e201bd?CorrelationId=56424a6e-43c0-4866-9596-8c68a23d50fb&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#BM2 и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285686/excel-use-a-cell-value-as-a-parameter-for-a-sql-query
про Access не понял что вы имеете в виду